# How to grab a pattern only if it surrounded by white space?

Tags: python-3.x

I'd like to grab count the number of time a substring appears within a string only if the substring is surrounded by white space.

example:

`string="java. java"
sub_string="java"`

number of times java appears is 1.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by "surrounded by whitespace"? I would have expected that to require whitespace after the second "java" in order to match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following solution detects if the substring is surrounded by whitespaces on both sides. If the string is "java. java ", then the length of the resulted list is 1. Same code will return empty list if the string is "java. java".

'\s' refers to the whitespace in python re module.

```
import re
string="java. java "
sub_string="java"
res = re.findall('\\s'+sub_string+'\\s',string)
print(res)
```

Thank you